# Rendering hair curves only

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

Is it possible to render fur or hair created by hair nodes without the underlying geometry like a plane or a modeled mesh?

Comment: yes, just hid the mesh or delete it )the mesh, not the hair). it doesn't even have to be parented to a mesh at all.